# Unexpected loop behavior

Tags: javascript, function

So I tried running the code below but it won't cycle through the array, 'contacts', and run the printPerson function. How do I make it print both info on bob and Mary.

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}

var list = function() {
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;
    for (i=0; i > contacts.length; i++) {
        printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
};
list();
```

Comment: It should be `i < contacts.length`. Please debug your code yourself first, this is a quite obvious mistake / typo.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you defining `contactsLength` and never use it?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to erase that, I'm new to javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the for loop:

```
for (i=0; i > contacts.length; i++)
            ^------------Change to <
```

Answer (score 1):

Change: `i > contacts.length` by `i < contacts.length` in your for loop

Answer (score 1):

Look into for cicle
 It shall be `i < contacts.length` instead of `i > contacts.length`